# How to query Array in MongoDB?

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

i am new to MongoDB and I have documents as below

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("604b7d62b19a72a2b89028e6"), "name" : "ram", "tags" : [ "mobile", "iphone", "india" ] }
{"_id" : ObjectId("604b7d83b19a72a2b89028e7"), "name" : "shyam", "tags" : [ "mobile", "iphone", "india" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("604b7d9bb19a72a2b89028e8"), "name" : "ravi", "tags" : [ "mobile", "android", "india" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("604b7db5b19a72a2b89028e9"), "name" : "aman", "tags" : [ "mobile", "android", "india" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("604b7db5b19a72a2b89028e9"), "name" : "aman", "tags" : [ "windows", "usa" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("604b7db5b19a72a2b89028e9"), "name" : "aman", "tags" : [ "tech", "apple", "microsoft" ] }
```

How to write query so that if i query for following tags `["mobile", "android", "12", "pro"]` i would get following result

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("604b7d9bb19a72a2b89028e8"), "name" : "ravi", "tags" : [ "mobile", "android", "india" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("604b7db5b19a72a2b89028e9"), "name" : "aman", "tags" : [ "mobile", "android", "india" ] } 
{ "_id" : ObjectId("604b7d62b19a72a2b89028e6"), "name" : "ram", "tags" : [ "mobile", "iphone", "india" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("604b7d83b19a72a2b89028e7"), "name" : "shyam", "tags" : [ "mobile", "iphone", "india" ] }
```

Comment: Query result and sample out is exactly the same, can you please elaborate on a query for the following tags `["mobile", "android", "12", "pro"]` ? you want documents matching all or any of them ? add some failing cases also in sample documents.

Comment: Ok i have added some failing cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/EMW8xgV1yrU

Use [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)

> The $in operator selects the documents where the value of a field equals any value in the specified array. To specify an $in expression, use the following prototype:

```
db.collection.find({
  tags: { $in: [ "mobile", "android", "12", "pro" ] }
})
```